# Is it possible to trigger a dependent build only in case the first in the chain is built from default branch?

Tags: git, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

Here is the scenario: I have a simple build chain of two configurations, the first builds the package, the other one deploys it and runs integration tests. Now the VCS root monitors master branch and pull requests (`refs/pull/*/merge`).

I would like it to work this way:

- if there's a pull request, only the first configuration is triggered (but not the dependent one)
- if there's a push to master, the whole chain runs

Is that possible to configure in TeamCity? Alternatively, is it possible through the REST API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume, the deploy configuration has snapshot dependency on build configuration.

TeamCity VCS trigger can have branch filter, that limits triggering to some *logical branch name*.

- To have logical names like `pull/*`, change the branch spec in vcs root to

  `refs/(pull/*)/merge`
- Add vcs trigger in "Build" configuration, with Branch Filter set to:

  `+:pull/*`
- Add vcs trigger in "Deploy" configuration, with Branch Filter set to:

  `+:<default>`

This should trigger Build on pull requests and Build + Deploy on commits to default (master) branch.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like what I'm looking for. I'll give it a try and get back. One question, though: should Deploy have "finish build trigger" towards Build? or  is it enough to have VCS trigger + Snapshot Dependency?

Comment: No, you do not need `Deploy` to have finish build trigger.
TeamCity will trigger deploy based on VCS trigger and will make sure it is linked with proper `Build` instance (either re-built, or re-used if applicable and configured in snapshot dependency settings)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot!